# Apache kafka compacted topic not working and data order wrong

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have written a Kafka application. In this application data is written to a topic and read out again. This is done with a simple consumer and producer.

The topic is a compacted topic

```
cleanup.policy = compact
min.cleanable.dirty.ratio = 0.01
delete.rentention.ms = 100
segment.ms = 100
```

This is how duplicate keys should be deleted.

1. Deleting duplicate data works only if the data is written first and then read a little later. It does not work if data is read and written at the same time.
2. If data is first written and then read, the order of the data is lost.

My Producer:

```
@Slf4j
public class FlightDataTestProducer {
    private static final Properties props = new Properties();
    public FlightDataTestProducer() {
        configureProps();
    }
public void configureProps() {
    props.put(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, "500");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, "33554432");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "kafka_flightdata_api_Producer");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "snappy");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.CONNECTIONS_MAX_IDLE_MS_CONFIG, "540000");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.DELIVERY_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "120000");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, "true");           
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, "0");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION, "5");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, "1");       
    props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG, "60000");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE_CONFIG, "1048576");       
    props.put(ProducerConfig.METADATA_MAX_AGE_CONFIG, "30000");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.METRICS_NUM_SAMPLES_CONFIG, "1");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.METRICS_RECORDING_LEVEL_CONFIG, "DEBUG");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.METRICS_SAMPLE_WINDOW_MS_CONFIG, "1000" );
    props.put(ProducerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG,"30000");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, "0");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTION_TIMEOUT_CONFIG, "100");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
    props.put(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "");
    props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, true);
}
public void produce(ConsumerRecord<ArrivalKey, Arrival> record) {
    try (final KafkaProducer<ArrivalKey, Arrival> producer = new KafkaProducer<ArrivalKey, Arrival>(props)) {
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<ArrivalKey, Arrival>("test_flugdaten",0,record.key(),record.value()));
        Thread.sleep(200);
        producer.flush();
        producer.close();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My First Consumer where I get the data from:

```
@Slf4j
public class FlightDataArrivalConsumer{

    private static final Properties props = new Properties();
public FlightDataArrivalConsumer() {
    configureProps();
}

public void configureProps() {     
   props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"");
   props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,"kafka_flightdata_api_Arrival");
   props.put(ConsumerConfig.METADATA_MAX_AGE_CONFIG,"50000");
   props.put(ConsumerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG,"30000");      
    props.put(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "");
    props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, true);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
}

public void consume () {
    try (final KafkaConsumer<ArrivalKey, Arrival> consumerArrival = new KafkaConsumer<ArrivalKey, Arrival>(props)) {
        consumerArrival.subscribe(Collections.singleton(""));
        while (true) {
            final ConsumerRecords<ArrivalKey, Arrival> recordsArrival = consumerArrival.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
            for (final ConsumerRecord<ArrivalKey, Arrival> recordArrival : recordsArrival) {
                FlightDataTestProducer fldt = new FlightDataTestProducer();
                fldt.produce(recordArrival);
                try {
                    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("Arrivals.txt", true);
                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(writer);
                    bufferedWriter.write(recordArrival.value().getFlightnumberstring());
                    bufferedWriter.newLine();
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Consumer, that consumes the topic afterwards:

```
@Slf4j
public class FlightDataTestProducer {
    private static final Properties props = new Properties();
public FlightDataTestProducer() {
    configureProps();
}

public void configureProps() {
    props.put(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, "500");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, "33554432");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "kafka_flightdata_api_Producer");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "snappy");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.CONNECTIONS_MAX_IDLE_MS_CONFIG, "540000");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.DELIVERY_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "120000");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, "true");           
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, "0");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION, "5");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, "1");        
    props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG, "60000");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE_CONFIG, "1048576");       
    props.put(ProducerConfig.METADATA_MAX_AGE_CONFIG, "30000");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.METRICS_NUM_SAMPLES_CONFIG, "1");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.METRICS_RECORDING_LEVEL_CONFIG, "DEBUG");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.METRICS_SAMPLE_WINDOW_MS_CONFIG, "1000" );
    props.put(ProducerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG,"30000");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, "0");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTION_TIMEOUT_CONFIG, "100");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
    props.put(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "");
    props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, true);
}

public void produce(ConsumerRecord<ArrivalKey, Arrival> record) {
    try (final KafkaProducer<ArrivalKey, Arrival> producer = new KafkaProducer<ArrivalKey, Arrival>(props)) {
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<ArrivalKey, Arrival>("",0,record.key(),record.value()));
        Thread.sleep(200);
        producer.flush();
        producer.close();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So has anybody an idea how i can solve this problem?

Comment: FWIW, I suggest MirrorMaker for moving data between topics and Kafka Connect for writing to files. But, compaction doesn't have time to do anything if your consumer has zero lag, so sounds like it's working as expected. Order is persevered in the topic, though. Please clarify this point... Maybe you shouldn't create a new FlightDataTestProducer for every single consumed record and set MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION=1?

Comment: The whole thing is first of all a test before the introduction in the company. Anyway, the Kafka compacted-topics should distribute the data from one system to another. There were already systems for the data, but they are outdated.
You say that I should not create a new producer every time.
So I should then collect several messages in a record and then send it bundled? In addition, when reading should then always be a small waiting time inside that the compacted topic can do its thing? For example with Thread.sleep(x) in the consumer?

Comment: Overall, I feel you may be using compacted topics incorrectly. They are primarily used to build materialized views like database tables (on in-memory `ConcurrentHashmap`) to _query_ later (refer docs on Kafka Streams Interactive Queries feature, or look at KSQLdb).  They are not a way to de-duplicate real-time events. For that, you could use Redis, for example, to query/overwrite unique key-values. Regarding the producer - create a singe instance outside of your loop. Or use MirrorMaker, like I said.

Comment: Yes. The other system are now also already Kafka. So we do not want to purchase something new now. The Compacted topics were also configured correctly. My producer had destroyed the order and the de-duplicate also worked as it should. Anyway, in the topic should just always be the latest key.

Comment: All the solutions I mentioned are free, by the way. There's no way to guarantee a topic will always only have unique keys without external systems to prevent duplicates at produce-time. More specifically the latest segment of a topic will not be compacted until its closed, even if you set it to a really small time frame (plus, that opens a lot of file handles on the broker, which is not recommended)